# Cross platform way to read Excel files in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I have some (Excel 2000) workbooks. I want to extract the data in each worksheet to a separate file.

I am running on Linux.

Is there a library I can use to access (read) XLS files on Linux from Python?

Comment: could always export the excel spreadsheet to csv format which should be easy to parse in Python

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.python-excel.org/?

Comment: Or save as XML and use XML parser.

Comment: +1 @Sven, python-excel looks perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.htm might work for you.

Comment: +1: xlrd has always worked flawlessly for me.  It does not read the latest Excel format yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @EOL: An "alpha" version of code that reads Excel 2007 xls[xm] files is available by e-mail request to serious testers. Just ask.

Answer (score 3):

Get `xlrd` [from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). Also go to [the python-excel website](http://www.python-excel.org) to find out about (a) a tutorial (b) a discussion group (c) `xlwt` and `xlutils`.

[Dis]claimer: I'm the author & maintainer of `xlrd`, and maintainer of `xlwt` (which is a fork of pyExcelerator with bugs fixed and numerous enhancements).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to run excel up under Wine or as a VM and do it from Windows.  You can use Mark Hammond's COM bindings, which come bundled with ActiveState Python.  Alternatively, you could export the data in CSV format and read it from that.

Comment: I'd be interested in your reasons for saying that win32 COM + Excel would be easier than `xlrd`

Comment: Gives you access to named ranges and the whole Excel API.  I have used xlrd and it works pretty much cell by cell.  You can get a whole sheet out at a time and work with it en masse through the API.

Comment: xlrd gives access to named ranges. The OP is on Linux and wants to extract the data(for which xlrd provides row-at-a-time access); he doesn't need "the whole Excel API" and the whole overhead of setting up a Windows-compatible environment and probably doesn't even have/want a licenced copy of Excel.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using [pyexcelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator) for this purpose in the past with good results.

Comment: currently this is better performed with xlrd and xlwt libraries. AFAIK pyexcelerator is not maintained anymore

Comment: -1 pyExcelerator ia abandonware (check out the bug tracker on sourceforge). Its xls reading component has minimal functionality.

Comment: @joaquin: maybe, just telling from own experience (we had some code written with it in production) and I've checked, it is still in the repo :)